# Unable to fetch photos from Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, image, google-cloud-firestore, nextjs-image

```
const PostCard = ({ post }) => {
  const [authorData, setAuthorData] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    const getAuthorData = async () => {
      setAuthorData(
        await (await getDoc(doc(db, 'users', post.data.author))).data(),
      )
    }

    getAuthorData()
  }, [post])

  return (
    <div>
    <Link href={`/post/${post.id}`}>
      <div className={styles.wrapper}>
        <div className={styles.postDetails}>
          <div className={styles.authorContainer}>
            <div className={styles.authorImageContainer}>
              {authorData && (
                <Image
                  src={`https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/fetch/${authorData?.imageurl}`}
                  alt='author'
                  className={styles.authorImage}
                  height={40}
                  width={40}
                />
              )}
            </div>
            <div className={styles.authorName}>{authorData?.name}</div>
          </div>
          <h1 className={styles.title}>{post.data.title}</h1>
          <div className={styles.briefing}>{post.data.brief}</div>
          <div className={styles.detailsContainer}>
            <span className={styles.articleDetails}>
              {new Date(post.data.postedOn).toLocaleString('en-US', {
                day: 'numeric',
                month: 'short',
              })}
              • {post.data.postLength} min read •{' '}
              <span className={styles.category}>{post.data.category}</span>
            </span>
            <span className={styles.bookmarkContainer}>
              <FiBookmark className='h-5 w-5' />
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.thumbnailContainer}>
          <Image
            src={`https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/fetch/${post.data?.bannerImage}`}
            alt='thumbnail'
            height={100}
            width={100}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </Link>
    </div>
  )
}

export default PostCard
```

[image: The error showing]
[image: Firebase configurations]

I Expected to be able to fetch images from firebase database.
I'm able to fetch all other components except image.
I tried to fetch images from cloudinary but it's not giving response and not showing image neither.
note :- Also added domain in nextconfig.js and also imported all but not maintioned here to reduce code.

Comment: How is your code related to Firebase?? The [Cloud Storage doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files) gives several examples.

Comment: I'm not able to fetch images from firebase firestore.

Comment: Have you followed the examples in the doc? If yes, what are the errors and can you share the corresponding code?